# Define a Custom Iterator in PHP 5.4.x?

Tags: php

Does PHP (5.4.x) allow one to create custom iterators **that can be dropped into foreach loops**?
(I have seen an iterator example that was fairly clunky)

I am accessing a web API that only allows one to pull N rows/objects per call, which results in clunky local code - i.e. an outer loop for grabbing a batch of data from the API and an inner loop for processing the elements of each batch.

I would prefer to push the outer loop into an iterator (that pulls down blocks of data and keeps track of the index into the external API etc) so I can write code more like this:

```
$datastream = new ApiIterator(/*params here*/);
foreach($datastream as $row){
   // do inner loop processing here
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Yes, Iterator classes can be a bit clunky due to the amount of boilerplate code required to write a basic iterator. You might be interested to know that PHP 5.5 (currently in beta, final release due out soon) includes a feature called Generators which allows similar functionality to iterators, but with much less code. There are still cases where it would be better to write an iterator, but generators will be a good replacement for most of the more simple use cases for iterators.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible from PHP 5.0, you need to use the PHP's Class Iterator interface ( http://php.net/manual/en/class.iterator.php ) and extend it (implement) in your ApiIterator Class